# Angular reactive forms: valueChanges doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I'm learning to use Reactive Forms in Angular 6, so forgive me if this question is stupid, but here's my issue:

I want to monitor for changes of a certain value in my reactive form, because when a change occurs I need to run some logic that recalculates stuff based on the new values. So I've tried doing this:

```
this.inputGroup = formBuilder.group({
  myControl: 'something'
});

this.inputGroup.get('myControl').valueChanges.subscribe(newVal => {
  console.log("new value", newVal); //Prints the correct new value
  console.log("actual value", this.inputGroup.value.myControl); //Prints the previous (old) value!

  this.someFuncThatExpectsTheValuesToBeUpToDate(); //This will find the OLD value inside this.inputGroup.value.myControl, instead of the new one!
});
```

but, as you can see from the comments I put in the code, this doesn't work because `valueChanges` seems to get called **before** the value is actually changed in the model! Is this intended behavior? The method signature for `valueChanges` says:

> A multicasting observable that emits an event every time the value of
>   the control changes, in the UI or programmatically.

so I would have assumed that it was called AFTER the value was changed in the form, but apparently not... is this correct? And if so, how can I detect when the value has actually changed in the control?

**EDIT**: there seems to be some confusion (as always here on SO :D) about WHY I want my function to access the data directly from the Form group, instead of passing the new value to the function itself. This is easily explained: the function gathers data from several form groups and uses this data to do some side-calculations. By accessing the data directly from the form groups, the function is generic and can be invoked from anywhere. If I start to put input parameters there, this would break. Take this example:

```
someFuncThatExpectsTheValuesToBeUpToDate(){
  let val1 = inputGroup.value.myControl;
  let val2 = someOtherFormGroup.value.myOtherControl;
  let val3 = yetAnotherFormGroup.value.someOtherControl;
  //do something with the vals
}
```

With this function, I can invoke it from anywhere and it will work. But if I need to pass in the values each time, I would need 3 different functions with different signatures to do the same thing, much more messy and complicated.

Comment: Are you saying your finction "someFuncThatExpectsTheValuesToBeUpToDate" is not getting updated value?

Comment: @DheerajKumar: exactly, basically when `valueChanges` fires the underlying value in the controls is not updated yet, it still holds the old value.

Comment: Don't you think you need to pass the changed value to your function? Since out of subscriber, it will be out of scope.

Comment: `console.log("actual value", inputGroup.value.myControl);` What is `inputGroup` here anyway? And what are you trying to accomplish? Why don't you just pass `newVal` to your method which needs it?

Comment: @DheerajKumar: Yes, I could pass the new value as a workaround, but I would prefer if the function obtains the values directly from the current model. This makes the function more generic and I can invoke it from different points in my code.

Comment: Can you show code of that function?

Comment: @ritaj: it's a form group (see first line in the code). I don't want to pass the value directly because I want this function to be generic: it gathers the values from various FormGroups (this is just one of them) and does some calculations based on those values. By accessing the values directly from the groups the function is generic and can be invoked from anywhere.

Comment: console.log("actual value", inputGroup.value.myControl); //  hope you are using this.inputGroup

Comment: @DheerajKumar: i've updated my answer

Comment: @FranklinPious: yes, sorry it was a typo, edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `valueChanges` event is fired after the new value is updated to the FormControl value, and before the change is bubbled up to its parent and ancestors. Therefore, you will have to access the value of the FormControl itself, not a field of the FormGroup value object.

console.log   `this.inputGroup.get('myControl').value` inside the subscribe and it will be having the new value.

Comment: Thanks Franklin, this was the correct answer! I'm very new to angular and apparently I did not properly understand the difference between the two. If I understand correctly: I was accessing the values as set in the FormGroup (basically: the values that are used to generate/populate the controls) instead of accessing the current data in the control itself. Am I correct?

Comment: @Master_T Initially the form control value gets updated and then it gets bubbled up to the parent and updates the form and value. And you were trying the access the value of the form (parent) which was not yet updated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, much appreciated